# Problems with Angular

Tags: angular

Every time I try to launch my project I get this error:

`$ ng serve`

> Your global Angular CLI version (1.7.3) is greater than your local
>   version (1.6.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng set --global
>   warnings.versionMismatch=false".
>
> Cannot read property 'config' of null
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
>       at Class.run (D:\Projekte\Advanced-ban\webinterface\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:51:63)
>       at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (D:\Projekte\Advanced-an\webinterface\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:123:26)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear:  make local and global version the same.

Comment: Read the error message. Make the versions the same or disable the warning exactly as stated in the error message.

Comment: check on which class you have defined config property and check its initialized or not

Comment: just for your info, please start accepting answers which resolve your isssue  : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The first on is warning .. to remove it follow update guid : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

> Your global Angular CLI version (1.7.3) is greater than your local
>   version (1.6.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

second one its error which is not related to first one

> Cannot read property 'config' of null
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
>       at Class.run (D:\Projekte\Advanced-ban\webinterface\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:51:63)
>       at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (D:\Projekte\Advanced-an\webinterface\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:123:26)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

which says that, you are reading `config` property of class which is not intialized. which means you class is in `undefiend/null` state. to make it work you need to initialize class

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install the specific version of CLI with respect to the project you installed.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.8
```